# WiX Installer DLL missing dependency

Tags: .net, dll, wix, installation, typelib

I currently working on an installer with WiX 3.8.
The installer is for a MS Project Add-In that is able for interop.
It works fine if I put all files in one directory and run `regasm /codebase /tlb foobar.dll`.
Now for the installer I:

- generate the TypeLib
- then unregister it with "regasm /unregister foobar.dll".
- run heat over the DLL and TypeLib with an xslt transformation to set

DLL

```
File/@Assembly=".net"
File/@Source="MyPath"
```

TLB

```
File/@Source="MyPath"
```

The installation itself run fine. The MS Project Add-In running from MS Project run fine too! But if I wan't to access functions via interop I get the error that

> "Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll" or its dependencies
>   not found.

The `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll` is in the `ApplicationDirectory` too.

Have someone an idea?

Comment: How are you installing those Office files? The best approach is probably to install the VSTOR redist as a prerequisite, like this for Office 2010. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44074

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll only depends on .NET 4 framework assemblies

Comment: VSTOR is installed. The MS Project Add-In run without errors. The Problem is that if I want to access the DLL via the TypeLib the error appears and I don't Understand why. @Morten Frederiksen: It is a .NET4 assembly

Comment: Ok my fault. The VSTOR was not installed. After installion of VSTOR everything runs fine. Tanks ;)